# Moving My Existing Spring APP to HTTPS

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, ssl, https

I want that my app should use some third party APIs with ssl .

Step 1 : I created key at my home directory  `keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keypass mypassword -keystore TestKeyStore.keystore -storepass mypassword -keyalg RSA -validity 360 -keysize 2048`

Step 2 :I added connector in server.xml from eclipse

```
<Connector port="8443" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150"
            minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="true"
            disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" debug="0" scheme="https"
            secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
            keystoreFile="/media/prashant/important/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/conf/TestKeyStore.keystore"
            keystorePass="mypassword" />
```

When I restart project tomcat Is taking to long time to start and it show nothing at the end . I tried to increase startup time also still not help me. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Paste the contents of your catalina.out, you will get an error there. Also, Spring wont just magically move to https. In your Spring-Security configuration, you must indicate which URL's you want under https.

Answer (score 0):

Please give more information. But i would check if you have allowed port 8443 in your firewall. To check its allowed, (if its a Linux machine) run telnet  8443. You will connect, meaning its allowed. Otherwise, details from logs will help further